# Compare two workbook and copy last column if the rest of data matches

Tags: vba, excel

Here is a bit of background on what I'm trying to achieve.

I have 2 excel files (Old and New), which contains around 10-15 sheets and each of the sheets contain many rows of data and total number of columns in each sheet is different.

I have reviewed Old file and placed my comments for all the rows in the last column of data in each sheet.

Now whenever I receive a New file, I need to first compare the Sheet name, if matches compare the Row of that sheet to old one if found copy the comment from last column of Old sheet to new one.

In short it's kind of reconciliation sheet.I have tried the following code but not getting how to loop for comparison of Workbook and then rows.

```
Sub recon()

Dim wb As Workbook
Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim sht2 As Worksheet
Dim rnge As Range

Set wb = Workbooks("OldWB")

For Each sht In wb.Sheets

    On Error Resume Next

    Set sht2 = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sht.Name)

    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not sht2 Is Nothing Then

        For Each rnge In sht.UsedRange

            If sht2.Range(rnge.Address).Value = "" And rnge.Value <> "" Then 
             Copy sht2.Range(rnge.Address).Offset(0,1).Value = rnge.Value                                       
            End If
                    Next rnge

        Set sht2 = Nothing

    End If
    Next sht
    Set wb = Nothing
```

End Sub

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. [Please look at this and edit your question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Did I asked someone to write code for me?
I don'tr think so. My question was Will VBA  work or is there any formulas that can achieve this?

Comment: Have you stepped through your code and seen if it enters the `if` condition?

Comment: given that `Copy sht2.Range(rnge.Address).Offset(0,1).Value = rnge.Value` won't compile, please give more details to help us help you. for instance you may want to better develop: _"I need to first compare the Sheet name, if matches compare the Row of that sheet to old one if found copy the comment from last column of Old sheet to new one."_

Answer (score 0):

Consider following points:
**1.** This code will give you desired result if sheets in both the workbook are in same order.
**2.** I am counting number of columns for each row assuming that the number of columns may vary row to row in each sheet. If this is not the case you can assign values to `lastColumnCurr` and `lastColumnOld` at the beginning of `For Each` loop.

```
Sub recon()
    Dim wbOld As Workbook
    Dim wsOld As Worksheet, wsCurr As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowCurr As Long, lastRowOld As Long, lastColumnCurr As Long, lastColumnOld As Long
    Dim i As Long, j As Long
    Dim flag As Boolean

    Set wbOld = Workbooks("old_test")

    For Each wsOld In wbOld.Sheets
        lastRowOld = wsOld.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        On Error Resume Next

        Set wsCurr = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(wsOld.Name)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not wsCurr Is Nothing Then
            'get number of rows in current sheet
            lastRowCurr = wsCurr.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
            'loop through all the rows
            For i = 1 To lastRowCurr
                'get number of columns in old and current sheets
                lastColumnOld = wsOld.Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                lastColumnCurr = wsCurr.Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                'maintain a boolean to check whether all the values in a row are same or not
                flag = True
                'now loop through all the columns in a row
                'here if the row in current sheet is same as the old sheet then there will be one column...
                '...less in current sheetin compared to old sheet because of your comment column at the end...
                '...hence lastColumnOld - 1
                If lastColumnCurr = lastColumnOld - 1 Then
                    For j = 1 To lastColumnCurr
                        'now all the cells in a row in both sheets
                        If wsOld.Cells(i, j).Value <> wsCurr.Cells(i, j).Value Then
                            'if cell is not same, change boolean to false
                            flag = False
                            Exit For
                        End If
                    Next j
                    'if boolean is false then there is difference in rows so do not add comment at the end
                    If flag = True Then
                        wsCurr.Cells(i, j).Value = wsOld.Cells(i, j).Value
                    End If
                End If
            Next i
            Set wsCurr = Nothing
        End If
    Next wsOld
    Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

**EDIT# 1**
**_________________________________________________________________________________**

Following code will match each row of active sheet to all rows of the sheet in old workbook.

```
Sub CompareRows_Mrig()
    Dim wbOld As Workbook
    Dim wsOld As Worksheet, wsCurr As Worksheet
    Dim lastRowCurr As Long, lastRowOld As Long, lastColumnCurr As Long, lastColumnOld As Long
    Dim flag As Boolean

    Set wbOld = Workbooks("old_test")

    For Each wsOld In wbOld.Sheets
        lastRowOld = wsOld.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

        On Error Resume Next

        Set wsCurr = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(wsOld.Name)
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not wsCurr Is Nothing Then

            lastRowCurr = wsCurr.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

            Dim c As Long
            Dim rIdx As Long, cIdx As Long

            For rIdx = 1 To lastRowCurr
                lastColumnCurr = wsCurr.Cells(rIdx, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
                c = 0
                For rIdx2 = 1 To lastRowOld
                    lastColumnOld = wsOld.Cells(rIdx2, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 1
                    If lastColumnCurr = lastColumnOld Then
                        flag = True
                        For cIdx = 1 To lastColumnCurr
                            If wsCurr.Cells(rIdx, cIdx).Value <> wsOld.Cells(rIdx2, cIdx).Value Then                                    
                                flag = False
                                Exit For
                            End If
                        Next
                        c = c + 1
                        Debug.Print c
                        If flag = True Then
                            wsCurr.Cells(rIdx, cIdx).Value = wsOld.Cells(rIdx2, cIdx).Value  
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            Next
        End If
    Next wsOld
    Set wb = Nothing
End Sub
```

**EDIT# 2**
**_________________________________________________________________________________**

To Speed up the code add following lines in sub:

```
Sub CompareRows_Mrig()
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    '*****************************
    'Put Code Here
    '*****************************

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: Works like charm! However when the rows are shuffled or extra row is found in the list then the macro doesn't copy the comment for rest of the rows.

Comment: @FunnyDragon - As per question `first compare the Sheet name, if matches compare the Row of that sheet to old one` that's what is being done here. This code do not compare row in acivesheet to all the rows in old workbook.

Comment: Thank you so much @Mrig for your help! I'll have to fins a work around to compare the rows with all in the old workbook.

Comment: @FunnyDragon - Let me give it a try in sometime.

Comment: That would really help. I didn't wanted to bother for more help as I already got a negative rating. I was not able to explain my problem in proper manner as my first or even second language is not English.

Comment: Hey @Mrig, thanks for the code, it helped but it's extremely slow. I had data of 1280 rows and it took more than 15 minutes to copy the comments. Tried several times but still slow. However thank you so much for your help..

Comment: @hellboy - If execution time is issue then write 
    `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` and 
    `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` at the beginning of your code and at the end add 
    `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` and
    `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic`. This will speed up the code.

Comment: Got it worked. I wan tot make it more easy, is there a way to get file name by user selection, instead of entering name every time.? Tried getting file name
Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).Show
 sFullName = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen).SelectedItems(1)
Workbooks.Open Filename:=sFullName
sFullName = Mid(sFullName, InStrRev(sFullName, "\") + 1)
sFullName = Left(sFullName, InStrRev(sFullName, ".") - 1)
Set wbOld = Workbooks(sFullName)

Comment: yup.. it shows debug and takes to the *Set wbOld = Workbooks(sFullName)*

Comment: @hellboy - Its working fine for me. While debugging what is the value for `sFullName`?

Comment: Workbooks.Open Filename:=sFullName
    sFullName = Mid(sFullName, InStrRev(sFullName, "\") + 1)
    sFullName = Left(sFullName, InStrRev(sFullName, ".") - 1)

Comment: @hellboy - No not this. When you debug code using F8, what is the value of `sFullName` at line `Set wbOld = Workbooks(sFullName)`

Comment: @hellboy - Uncomment this line: `Workbooks.Open Filename:=sFullName`

Comment: tried all alternatives. no success. Is there any way to prompt user to get the value for `Set wbOld = Workbooks("MSLabData")`

Comment: @hellboy - Debug the code and check the value of `sFullName` in `Set wbOld = Workbooks(sFullName)`. You are getting this error because file is not available to excel.

Comment: Somehow I got it working, however I also added time to check the  exact processing time. And it's lagging like hell. I have 20 tabs and 4k rows. If there is any alternative way to compare and populate the data or else I will have to work on excel using Concatenate and vlookups.  :(